# Display pageviewcontroller in Segue destinationviewcontroller

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios6, uistoryboardsegue

I have a pdfviewcontroller as a segue destinationviewcontroller in which i want to display pageviewcontroller.

```
- (IBAction)ReadAction:(id)sender {

[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"MySegue" sender:sender];

}


- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
 if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"MySegue"]) {

// Get destination view
PDFViewController *pdfviewController = [segue destinationViewController];
}
 }
```

In pdfviewcontroller had code to display pageviewcontroller

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Paper" ofType:@"pdf"];
PageViewController *page = [[PageViewController alloc] initWithPDFAtPath:path];
//[self presentViewController:page animated:NO completion:NULL];
```

If i use this statement

```
//[self presentViewController:page animated:NO completion:NULL];
```

then it doesn't display navigation bar and backbarbuttonitem

reason is that segue is already set up in the storyboard and there is no need to call presentViewController.

But when i remove this statement

```
 //[self presentViewController:page animated:NO completion:NULL];
```

then it doesn't display pageviewcontroller only it displays navigation bar and backbarbuttonitem.

and when i replace this statement

```
//[self presentViewController:page animated:NO completion:NULL];
```

with this statement

```
 [self.view addSubview:page.view];
```

then it displays pageviewcontroller but doesn't turn page over at all. To turn page over using curl effect transition.

If i add this code

```
 NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Paper" ofType:@"pdf"];
PageViewController *page = (PageViewController *)[segue destinationViewController];
[page initWithPDFAtPath:path];
```

in prepare for segue to display pageviewcontroller in pdfviewcontroller then  i get this error

**Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '**-

```
[PDFViewController initWithPDFAtPath:]:
```

**unrecognized selector sent to instance**

If anyone could guide me in the right direction, would really appreciate it.

Thanks for help.

Comment: You need to remove the : unless you are passing arguments.

Comment: NSLog(@"PATH: %@",path);

Comment: add that right before your last line, I want to see if path comes back nil.

Comment: it still gives same error

Comment: In your debug window do you see PATH: and a path after it? What is it showing.

Comment: It is not showing path: actually my segue destinationviewcontroller is pdfviewcontroller in which i m trying to display pageviewcontroller

Comment: Ensure Paper.pdf is copied into your bundle, and also make sure the case is correct.

Comment: if u understand my problem correctly that this code was previously in pdfviewcontroller which is actually segue destinationviewcontroller to display pageviewcontroller. i tweeked the code little bit and added it in the preparefor segue to display pageviewcontroller. i want to keep my segue destinationviewcontroller same which is pdfviewcontroller