# PrepareforSegue not displaying destinationviewcontroller

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios6, uistoryboardsegue

Segue destinationviewcontroller pdfviewcontroller not displaying pageviewcontroller

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"MYSegue"]) {

    // Get destination view
    PDFViewController *pdfviewController = [segue destinationViewController];
    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"paper" ofType:@"pdf"];
    PageViewController *page = [[PageViewController alloc] initWithPDFAtPath:path];
    pdfviewController= page;

}
}
```

shows only navigation bar and backbuttonitem

and shows semantic issue incompatible pointer types assigning to pdfviewcontroller strong from pageviewcontroller strong.

Thanks for help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Display pageviewcontroller in Segue destinationviewcontroller](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17599528/display-pageviewcontroller-in-segue-destinationviewcontroller)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line is wrong:

> pdfviewController= page;

As the compiler tells you, the type is `PDFViewController *` and you're trying to assign `PageViewController *`.

Did you mean something like:

```
pdfviewController.page = page;
```

---

The segue should just do:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"MYSegue"]) {
        // Get destination view
        PDFViewController *pdfViewController = [segue destinationViewController];
        NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"paper" ofType:@"pdf"];

        pdfViewController.path = path;
    }
}
```

Add some properties to the pdf view controller:

```
@property (copy, nonatomic) NSString *path;
@property (strong, nonatomic) PageViewController *page;
```

Then in the pdf view controller

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    PageViewController *page = [[PageViewController alloc] initWithPDFAtPath:self.path];
    page.view.frame = self.view.bounds;
    [self.view addSubview:page.view];
    [self addChildViewController:page];
    self.page = page;
}
```

Comment: i want to display pageviewcontroller in pdfviewcontroller

Comment: Ok, but what are they? Are they yours? Did you get them from github? How do you think they go together?

Comment: if you will look at my this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17599528/display-pageviewcontroller-in-segue-destinationviewcontroller you might understand my problem. Thanks for your time and help.

Comment: You shouldn't repost the same question again, edit the original instead.

Comment: And the other question doesn't say anything about the class definitions. Why are you trying to use 2 view controllers, what is the relationship between them supposed to be (and why isn't it encapsulated in the PDF view controller)?

Comment: Reason is that segue is already set up in the storyboard and there is no need to call presentViewController. In the pdfviewcontroller i had actual code which is this NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Paper" ofType:@"pdf"];
PageViewController *page = [[PageViewController alloc] initWithPDFAtPath:path];
//[self presentViewController:page animated:NO completion:NULL]; if i remove last statement then it doesn't show pagevc only shows navigation bar and backitem. that is why i moved this piece of code in prepareforsegue

Comment: So why doesn't the PDF view controller still do that and then add the page view controller as a child view controller and the view as a subview?

Comment: if i use this statement [self presentViewController:page animated:NO completion:NULL]; only then it displays pagevc in pdfvc but then doesn't shows navigation bar and back item and if i remove this statement then it doesn't shows pagevc only displays navigationbar and back item

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/33299/discussion-between-wain-and-user1120133)